# how to achive resend OTP using firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

how can Resend OTP after 60 sec. using firebase library, currently using this
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/phone-invisible.html

1. called this on first Send OTP

   ```
   window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', { 

   });
   ```

   Working fine its sending first OTP. but i have added timer if 60 sec. cross. it will Resend OTP button

   not its not send Next OTP so how can I achvie That?
2. On Resend OTP click calling Same

   ```
   window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', { 

   });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution:
On Resend we don't need to call the same Resend Button Click i.e.

```js
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', { });
```

instead, we can directly call the inner function

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
```

so OTP will be resent.

Comment: can you please share the full code?